# How to read key charcode in bash?

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

I have simple script written in bash:

```
#!/bin/bash
while true; do
read -rsn1 input
if [ "$input" = "a" ]; then
firefox;
fi
done
```

Is it possibile to read not char name but charcode correct to xmodmap command?

Comment: No. The terminal emulator converts everything to text input.

Comment: Well, that's true if you're reading from stdin. If one _runs_ xmodmap and reads its stdout, then you're no longer depending on what the terminal emulator gives you (though it's no longer really a "how do you do X in bash?" question, since it's principally about how to interoperate with tools that aren't part of bash / distributed with bash / etc).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I want distinguish pressed numeric key from numpad and "normal" numeric.

Comment: Makes sense. Everything Barmar and I said above remains accurate: The actual keypresses are given to the terminal emulator; the terminal emulator relays them on to the stdin of the program it's running (in this case, bash) after decoding. That "after decoding" process loses some information -- as a terminal program reading stdin, you don't know what the original keycode was, you just know that the terminal interpreted it as an `a`; so if you want to know the original values, you need to go _around_ the terminal emulator and get your data directly from something above it in the stack.

Comment: But it is possible? I am webdeveloper and bash is black magic for me.

Comment: I already told you that it's possible, and (at a very high level) how to do it. Go back and read the second sentence of my first comment again. That said, it's probably way more trouble than it's worth; personally, I'd find a different way to accomplish whatever the end-user experience you're looking for is.

Comment: There are plenty of tools like `xev` (https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/xev.1.html) that let you sniff X events, so you can see which keypresses are handed to your terminal (and any/every other program). Have your script run one of those programs to do the interception and parse events from its stdout, and there you are. But as I said, way more trouble than it's probably worth.